# Internationalization (i18n) + Translation Management - No interface for adding translator available

Tags: 6, i18n-l10n

In the **Translation Manager** menu (`http://<mysite>/admin/content/translation-management/manage-translator?from=en&to=hu`), when I want to add a translator to a given page, I see the following error message: **"No interface for adding translator available."**.

What should I do?
I think I gave the right permissions to the administrator and another given user (I checked the following permissions in "ICanLocalize translator" checkbox: "submit content for translation", "can do translation jobs", "can view translation jobs", "translate content", and gave "ICanLocalize translator" role to the admin and the other mentioned user), i18n module is installed, so I don't know what is missing.

Here's a screenshot:
[image: Translation Management - No interface for adding translator available.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime I found the answer: I just realized that ***"ICanLocalize translation service"*** module wasn't enabled.

After enabling, I can see the following:

[image: Translator interface OK now... Just after enabling "ICanLocalize translation service" module.]

So I think I can consider my problem solved. :)

---

You could also enable ***"Local translation service"*** module to add your local translators.